# Resharper Extension Manager is empty

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I'm working with VS2103 Update 5 and RS 10, the feed for the extensions is https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/api/v2/curated-feeds/Wave_v3.0/ and also tried changing https to http.

any time I open Resharper Extensions Manager, I get the extensions window blank and nothing loads.

[image: Resharper Extension Manager empty]

I'm working under a proxy, but all of my teammates have the same proxy configuration and I'm the only one that have this issue. I used fiddler to check the request, but no request is made at all.

Not sure if VS is blocking something or what's happening, but I've tried many things like updating to VS2015, uninstall and reinstall RS, downgrade RS from 10 to 9.2.

you have any idea of what could be happening here?

Answer (score 3):

This is almost certainly due to a proxy issue. It looks like ReSharper use nuget to deliver their packages. The old version of nuget was pretty much unstoppable at getting through the corporate proxy, but it seems like the new dotnetcore version has a bug in it that means that it can't get through the proxy for a lot of people: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2190. They seem to have recently closed the bug, but I've not tested to see if it works. It didn't a few months ago on our proxy which was an epic world of pain. Basically until they start referencing a version of the nuget dll with the fix it won't work.

However, you can manually download the package from their website and use that instead: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241675-Offline-plug-in-installation-process

When I did this I still got some warnings, but the extension (StyleCop) seemed to work OK.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have more than one source listed in the Extension Manager options? If there are two with the same name, it can get things confused and not work.

Next thing to try is to run [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), and see what's happening over the network. You should see the requests to the extension gallery, and what kind of responses you're getting back - 407 will tell you if it's a proxy issue, for example.

**UPDATE:** Hang on. ReSharper 10 should be `wave_v4.0`, not `wave_v3.0`. That looks like it's not been updated from 9.2.

Comment: 1. I don't have any other source but this : https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/api/v2/curated-feeds/Wave_v3.0/.

2. I ran Fiddler, but there's no requests **AT ALL** when opening the extensions manager

3. I uninstalled RS10 and I'm working right now with RS 9.2, also I've tried with both _wave_v3.0_ and _wave_v4.0_

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause of your problem can be the DPI settings (text and layout scale) on that monitor.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2019/06/11/blank-tool-windows-resharper-visual-studio-2019-net-framework-4-8-per-monitor-dpi-awareness

It's 2022 and I'm still struggling with this, despite I reset all to 100%.
(I haven't tried to logout and login again yet)